# How to generate a valid sas token with AzureStor in R with "sp" prefix?

Tags: r, azure-storage

I have been trying to generate a valid sas token with the code below. `storage_account_name` and `storage_account_key` have definitely been double checked by myself and a couple of others. For some reason when I create the token through this process I get a token that starts with `sv` but when I generate it on the portal I get one with `sp`.

I have tried changing the dates with `as.POSIXct` etc but even the documentation shows that `Sys.Date()` is acceptable so I am not sure what other argument or input should be different. Does anyone know what I am missing in generating a valid sas token?

```
library(AzureStor)

sas_token <- get_service_sas(
    account = config[["storage_account_name"]],
    resource = resource_name,
    key = config[["storage_account_key"]],
    service = "blob",
    permissions = "r",
    resource_type = "b",
    protocol = "https",
    start = Sys.time(),
    expiry = Sys.time() +1 
)
```

Comment: Ordering of parameters like sv and sp etc. is not important. What’s important is that these parameters are present in your SAS token. If you do not encounter any errors while using the SAS token, then your SAS token is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @Gaurav Mantri If you do not encounter any errors while using the SAS token, then your SAS token is valid.

**As per this [Document](https://rdrr.io/cran/AzureStor/man/sas.html), In storage account SAS token, there are two types.**

1. ***Account SAS** : An account SAS, secured by the storage account key, authorizes access to storage services’ resources. **It empowers delegation for operations like read, write, and delete on blob containers, tables, queues, and file shares.** Access similar to a user delegation SAS can be achieved by obtaining an account SAS through the `get_account_sas` call.*
2. ***Service SAS** : A service SAS provides more precise access control compared to an account SAS. **It enables creating SAS tokens that grant access exclusively to designated blobs in a container or files within a file share.** To generate a service SAS, you can use the `get_service_sas` call.*

You can also check in portal when you generate the SAS token for account in portal it will give the SAS token starting with `sv` and when you generate the token for any specific container you it will give the SAS token starting with `sp`

**You can try to generate the SAS token with `get_account_sas` as per above doc.**

```r
get_account_sas("mystorage", "access_key", start=Sys.Date(), expiry=Sys.Date() + 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of the parts in the string sv=***&ss=***&srt=***&...&sig=*** doesn't matter. What matters is the value of each part. You can see here the C++ SDK is also returning sv first like the R SDK.

I would suggest comparing the ss, srt, sp parts between the value generated by the SDK and one generated on Azure, maybe an argument is not correctly set.